# Можно ли использовать Enum без необходимости постоянно кастовать?

Tags: c#

Есть у меня перечисления. Очень большой список. Например:

```
enum State : byte { 
    IDLE,                       //0 - стойка
    WALK_F,                     //1 - ходьба вперёд
    WALK_B,                     //2 - ходьба назад
    BLOCK,                      //3 - блок
    SIT,                        //4 - сидение
    JUMP_UP,                    //5 - прыжок вверх
    JUMP_F,                     //6 - прыжок вперёд
    JUMP_B,                     //7 - прыжок назад
    BLOCK_SIT,                  //8 - блок в присядке
    TURN,                       //9 - поворот
    RUN,                        //10 - бег.
    ... и т.д.
};
```

Можно ли как-то применять эти значения в виде, представленным ниже?

```
byte test = State.RUN;
```

Или мне постоянно придется писать приведение к типу? Типа:

```
byte test = (byte)State.RUN;
```

Вроде бы если `enum` является перечислением из одного типа, то можно написать

`enum ENUM_NAME : TYPE { ... };`

и должно все работать. Но *IDE* упорно говорит что все равно надо кастовать. Может я что-то не понимаю.

Просто делать такое приведение типа абсолютно везде чересчур затратно. особенно если я решу тип сменить. Таких мест будет сотня. Тем более, если я заранее говорю, что у меня в перечислении будет всё одного конкретного типа, то почему бы такому не работать?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Язык вам тонко намекает, что кастовать туда-сюда между `enum` и целым типом — не самая здравая и строго типизированная мысль. Вам не должно хотеться повсеместно использовать тип `byte`, если у вас есть `enum` с базовым типом `byte`.

Просто используйте сам `enum` везде, где можно. Где нельзя — преобразуйте тип. И этой операции положено быть явной, потому что вы меняете тип переменной.

При этом какой у перечисления базовый тип — значения не имеет. Хоть `enum Foo : int` преобразовывать к `int`, хоть `enum Bar : byte` преобразовывать в `byte` — операция должна быть явной.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Что значит: "Просто используйте сам enum везде, где можно. Где нельзя — преобразуйте тип."

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что Enum очень хорош для конструкций switch, например `switch (state) {case State.RUN: doSomething; break; case State.WALK: doSomething; break; }`, а если я хочу делать что-то типа такого:
`if(ButtonPressed("Punch")) {timesPressed[ATTACK_TYPE_PUNCH]++; atkTimer[ATTACK_TYPE_PUNCH] = 0; atk[ATTACK_TYPE_PUNCH] = true; }` где `ATTACK_TYPE_PUNCH` - константа со значением. То лучше пользоваться константами?

Comment: То, что вы описываете, соответствует интерфейсу `IDictionary<State, T>`. Обычный словарь `Dictionary<,>` будет неоптимален для этого, но на большинстве задач разницу вы не заметите. При желании можно реализовать словарь на основе `List<>` или массива. Вообще, желание повсеместно пользоваться подобными массивами подозрительно, в этом я согласен с PavelMayorov.

Comment: Я кажется начал понимать что к чему. Вопрос мой был, видимо, из-за плохого понимания как работает этот тип. Сейчас вроде стало все понятно для чего он и почему все так.

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку в комментариях вы поинтересовались про использование перечисления в качестве индекса массива, отвечу.

Допустим, у нас есть перечисление `TEnum`, основанное на типе `int` (для простоты)

Тогда можно сделать вот так:

```
struct TEnumDict<T> {
    private readonly T[] values;

    TEnumDict() { values = new T[...]; }

    public T this[TEnum index] {
      get { return values[(int)index]; }
      set { values[(int)index] = value; }
    }
}
```

Такую структуру можно использовать вместо массива, и она прекрасно индексируется перечислением. Использование такой структуры практически не несет накладных расходов, поскольку все операции над ней очень простые и JIT их заинлайнит.

Если же подобных перечислений становится много - то можно добавить уровень обобщения, ценой некоторого замедления...

```
struct IntValuedEnumDict<T,E> {
    private static readonly Func<E, int> valueof;

    static IntValuedEnumDict() {
        var e = Expression.Parameter<E>();
        valueof = Expression.Lambda<Func<E, int>>(Expression.Convert(e, typeof(int)), p).Compile();
    }

    private readonly T[] values;

    IntValuedEnumDict() { values = new T[...]; } // Число элементов надо тоже определить в статическом конструкторе - но мне лень

    public T this[TEnum index] {
      get { return values[valueof(index)]; }
      set { values[valueof(index)] = value; }
    }
}
```

На самом деле, я не уверен, что такая конструкция будет работать быстро. Надо проверять.

Или можно не городить велосипеды, а воспользоваться классом [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Это не массив, а словарь, и работает он несколько медленнее - зато он готовый и универсальный.

---

Но задумайтесь вот над чем. Зачем вам вообще такие перечисления или константы? Учитесь мыслить объектно-ориентированно! Возможная атака - это тоже объект. Почему бы не сделать вот так:

```
class Attack {
    public int timesPressed;
    public int atkTimer;
    public bool atk;
}
```

Такой объект можно привязать напрямую к кнопке, избавившись тем самым не только от константы `ATTACK_TYPE_PUNCH` - но и от строкового литерала "Punch"!

Нужно выполнить действие над этими полями? Нет проблем:

```
class Attack {
    public int timesPressed;
    public int atkTimer;
    public bool atk;

    public void ButtonPressed() {
        timesPressed = 0;
        atkTimer = 0;
        atk = true;
    }
}
```

Для разных типов атак нужен разный код? Нет проблем:

```
abstract class Attack {
    public abstract void ButtonPressed();
    public abstract int AtkTimer { get; }
}

class PunchAttack : Attack {
    public int timesPressed;
    public int atkTimer;
    public bool atk;

    public override void ButtonPressed() {
        timesPressed = 0;
        atkTimer = 0;
        atk = true;
    }

    public override int AtkTimer { get { return atkTimer; } }
}
```

Comment: Да, атаку это я так в качестве примера привел. Но спасибо за совет